# Change the display name of order total

Tags: commerce

the following code to replace the displayed name of the subtotal.

How to change the display name of order total ?

```
// Rename subtotal.
function seven_subtheme_back_office_commerce_price_component_type_info_alter(&$component_types) {
  $component_types['base_price']['display_title'] = t('Sous-total hors remises');
}
```

the following code does not work, it must be poorly written :

```
// Rename subtotal.
function seven_subtheme_back_office_commerce_price_component_type_info_alter(&$component_types) {
  $component_types['base_price']['display_title'] = t('Sous-total hors remises');
  $components['commerce_price_formatted_amount']['title'] = t('ORDERrrrr TOTAL');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For changing order total, this line

```
// Replace ORDER TOTAL text as per your requirement.
$components['commerce_price_formatted_amount']['title'] = t('ORDER TOTAL');
```

should be added inside your above mentioned function. Check if it works.

Comment: thank you. I do not know how to write your code. I've updated the question

Comment: I can not find the code to put